# Meaning of "female eye" in a list of parts

Tags: terminology

[A fellow translator is translating a list of parts into Russian](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=4&MessNum=349503&l1=1&l2=2), and can't understand the meaning of "female eye". Here's the table:

> [image]

Maybe someone here could come up with some ideas about the possible meaning of this "female eye".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Eye" is very non specific, but I expect it to be an item with a female thread (like a nut). This could take any number of forms, however. I've illustrated two below, but more information from context etc. would be required for a more specific answer.

A "Female Eye Bolt" - Yes, it gets called '... bolt' despite being more like a nut. You would use this if, for example, you had studding welded to something.
[image: female eye bolt]

This one is a female "Heim Eye Bolt", sometimes called a "Rod End".

[image: Female Rod End]

Hopefully that give you a bit of an idea, and a route down which you can continue your own research.

Answer (score 2):

On some hydraulic cylinders there are different attachments on the ends called mounts.

Examples:

[image: Female Eye]
Female Eye

[image: Pin Eye]
Pin Eye

[image: Clevis]
Clevis

These go on the ends of some hydraulic cylinders like on this rack and pinion:

[image: Rack and Pinion]

Answer (score 1):

The operative engineering term is "screw" (no pun intended).

The screw itself is the "male" part, and the shaft into which a screw is inserted and rotated is a female part. The "eyes" referred to are "receivers" for screws, and are therefore categorized as "female".

The terminology is derived, of course, from animal anatomy, in which females are the recipients of "screw"-like actions.